# Inserting a loop to a JAVA password generetator

Tags: java, loops, passwords, generator

i need help with implementing a loop to my password generator. I tried it once but would not work cause the return value was missing. I want it to loop until i got 100 passwords.

This my code:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.Random;

public class generatePassword {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((12 - 8) + 1) + 8;
    private static final String CHAR_LOWERCASE = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private static final String CHAR_UPPERCASE = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    private static final String DIGIT = "0123456789";
    private static final int PASSWORD_LENGTH = 12;

    private static final String PASSWORD_ALLOW = CHAR_LOWERCASE + CHAR_UPPERCASE + DIGIT ;
    
    private static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generatePassword();
    }

    public static String generatePassword() {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(PASSWORD_LENGTH);
        String strLowerCase = generateRandomString(CHAR_LOWERCASE, 1);
        result.append(strLowerCase);
        String strUppercaseCase = generateRandomString(CHAR_UPPERCASE, 1);
        result.append(strUppercaseCase);
        String strDigit = generateRandomString(DIGIT, 1);
        result.append(strDigit);

       
        String strOther = generateRandomString(PASSWORD_ALLOW, PASSWORD_LENGTH - 3);
        result.append(strOther);

        String password = result.toString();
        // combine all
        System.out.format("%-20s: %s%n", "Password", password);
        System.out.format("%-20s: %s%n%n", "Password Length", password.length());

        return password;




    // generate a random char[], based on `input`
    private static String generateRandomString(String input, int size) {

        if (input == null || input.length() <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input.");
        if (size < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid size.");

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            // produce a random order
            int index = random.nextInt(input.length());
            result.append(input.charAt(index));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

I've also tried to put the "return password" outside the loop but it still didn't work.

This is the loop i tried:

```
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){  
}
```

Comment: 1) Class names should start with an upper case character. 2) Your loop does nothing. 3) Why would you loop 10 times if you want 100 passwords?

Comment: Move your `generateRandomString` outside of `generatePassword`. Method inside method won't work.

Comment: Why not create a new method ``public void generatePasswords(int n)`` which just loops n times and calls and prints the original method?

Answer (score 0):

If i got your intent clear from your question then to generate 100 passwords you need to loop through `100` times and call `generatePassword`.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Random;

public class GenerateRandom {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((12 - 8) + 1) + 8;
    private static final String CHAR_LOWERCASE = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private static final String CHAR_UPPERCASE = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    private static final String DIGIT = "0123456789";
    private static final int PASSWORD_LENGTH = 12;

    private static final String PASSWORD_ALLOW = CHAR_LOWERCASE + CHAR_UPPERCASE + DIGIT;

    private static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            generatePassword();
        }
    }

    public static String generatePassword() {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(PASSWORD_LENGTH);
        String strLowerCase = generateRandomString(CHAR_LOWERCASE, 1);
        result.append(strLowerCase);
        String strUppercaseCase = generateRandomString(CHAR_UPPERCASE, 1);
        result.append(strUppercaseCase);
        String strDigit = generateRandomString(DIGIT, 1);
        result.append(strDigit);


        String strOther = generateRandomString(PASSWORD_ALLOW, PASSWORD_LENGTH - 3);
        result.append(strOther);

        String password = result.toString();
        // combine all
        System.out.format("%-20s: %s%n", "Password", password);
        System.out.format("%-20s: %s%n%n", "Password Length", password.length());

        return password;

    }

    // generate a random char[], based on `input`
    private static String generateRandomString(String input, int size) {

        if (input == null || input.length() <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input.");
        if (size < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid size.");

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            // produce a random order
            int index = random.nextInt(input.length());
            result.append(input.charAt(index));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think the OP should learn to use a basic for loop first? The syntax is far easier to understand. If they can't get that straight how would they understand whatever it is you are suggesting.

Comment: Yes you are correct but i thought since OP might be very beginner(As he is `method inside method`) so we should help him out.

Comment: Exactly my point. A beginner should start with a simple for loop. The IntStrteam.range... is much more complicated. The OP even posted code for a for loop. All you had to do was invoke the method inside the loop instead or rewriting the entire looping code.